# How to go from bearer token to entity id?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, token

Likely a noob question which is answered best by pointing to something else than the direct answer, BUT:

I have setup a web api with identity authentication. When someone logs in they login with email/password by calling `/token`, which gives them the bearer token they can use.

However, what is the best practice to get company settings? Is that calling an `/customer?email=email` ? I guess my question really is: How do you go from token to customerid for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already creating a bearer token, you can put anything you want or need inside the token as claims.

If the company is not related to your account, then the beginning of your question (about the /token endpoint) is irrelevant,

Comment: As an example, when IdentityServer issues a token using the OIDC spec, it includes a `sub` claim that represents the ID of the user. The default example shown on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) demonstrates what this would look like.

Comment: True, but what is best practice here? For practicality, lets say we have a "customer service". This has two methods: "GetById" or "GetBySpecification" which is a generic method to get customers by different parameters.

What would be best practice? To add a token to the specification? To make a third method?

Comment: You get a token for authentication, and you should put everything you need inside it. However, we would need more details about entity relationships in your application to discuss more precisely. For example, is a user allowed to see any company?